# Why does my loop for values inside a HashMap stop?

Tags: java, for-loop, hashmap

I am trying to loop through available slot capacity within a HashMap. The part until the second else works as intended.

```
        int preferredSlot = 0;
        int numberOfSlots = 3;
        int capacityPerSlot = 3;
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> slots = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        int givenSlot = 100, count = 0;

        if (slots.size() < (numberOfSlots + 1) * (capacityPerSlot + 1)) {
            if (!slots.containsValue(preferredSlot)) {
                givenSlot = preferredSlot;
                slots.put(count, preferredSlot);
                count++;
            } else {
                int valueCount = 0;
                for (Object value : slots.values()) {
                    if (value.equals(preferredSlot)) {
                        valueCount++;
                    }
                }
                if (valueCount <= capacityPerSlot) {
                    givenSlot = preferredSlot;
                    slots.put(count, preferredSlot);
                    count++;
                } else {
                    int valueCount2 = 0;
                    int i = 1;
                    for (Object value : slots.values()) {
                        if (value.equals(preferredSlot + i)) {
                            valueCount2++;
                            System.out.println("i=" + i + "  count=" + valueCount2);
                            if (valueCount2 > capacityPerSlot) {
                                valueCount2 = 0;
                                i++;
                                System.out.println("i2=" + i + "  count2=" + valueCount2);     
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (valueCount2 <= capacityPerSlot) {
                        givenSlot = preferredSlot + i;
                        slots.put(count, i);
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Given Slot: "+givenSlot);
    }
}
```

I am only having problems with this loop:

```
} else {
                    int valueCount2 = 0;
                    int i = 1;
                    for (Object value : slots.values()) {
                        if (value.equals(preferredSlot + i)) {
                            valueCount2++;
                            System.out.println("i=" + i + "  count=" + valueCount2);
                            if (valueCount2 > capacityPerSlot) {
                                valueCount2 = 0;
                                i++;
                                System.out.println("i2=" + i + "  count2=" + valueCount2);     
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (valueCount2 <= capacityPerSlot) {
                        givenSlot = preferredSlot + i;
                        slots.put(count, i);
                        count++;
                    }
```

If I insert these test numbers into my map, there's only supposed to be 1 capacity left for slot 3.

```
        slots.put(100, 0);
        slots.put(101, 0);
        slots.put(102, 0);
        slots.put(122, 0);

        slots.put(103, 1);
        slots.put(104, 1);
        slots.put(105, 1);
        slots.put(120, 1);

        slots.put(106, 2);
        slots.put(107, 2);
        slots.put(108, 2);
        slots.put(121, 2);

        slots.put(110, 3);
        slots.put(111, 3);
        slots.put(112, 3);
```

But my console output looks like this:

```
i=1  count=1
i=1  count=2
i=1  count=3
i=1  count=4
i2=2  count2=0
i=2  count=1
Given Slot: 2
```

Why does my loop through the values stop at this point?
The `count` is supposed to go up to 4 and then increment `i` to 3. Afterwards the count should go up to 3 and finally my `givenSlot` should be 3. What am I doing wrong with this loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the values are iterated in no particular order. Do not expect the for loop to encounter them in the order in which you inserted them into the map.

Here:

```
for (Object value : slots.values()) {
    if (value.equals(preferredSlot + i)) {
```

You are filtering out the values that doesn't equal `preferredSlot + 1`, so if a value is not `preferredSlot + 1`, *it will not be checked again*. However, those values *need* to be checked again when `i` changes!

The loop stops because all the values in the map has been iterated through, *once*. When `i` was 1, you ignored a few 2's in the map. Now that `i` is 2, you don't actually encounter those 2's again, because the for loop only loops through the values *once*.

One way to fix this is to use a nested loop. The outer loop will repeat the `for (Integer value : slots.values())` loop. You can move the `int i;` and `i++;` statements into the outer loop header. The stopping condition would be when the map definitely does not contain the value `preferredSlot + i` - when `preferredSlot + i` is greater than `numberOfSlots`.

```
int i;
boolean found;
for (i = 0; preferredSlot + i <= numberOfSlots; i++) {
  found = true;
  for (Integer value : slots.values()) {
    if (value.equals(preferredSlot + i)) {
      valueCount2++;
      System.out.println("i=" + i + "  count=" + valueCount2);
      if (valueCount2 > capacityPerSlot) {
        valueCount2 = 0;
        found = false;
        break; // reached capacity
      }
    }
  }
  if (found) { // if this is true, we have never reached the first break
    break;
  }
}
if (valueCount2 <= capacityPerSlot) {
  givenSlot = preferredSlot + i;
  slots.put(count, i);
  count++;
}
```

Alternatively, use a little bit of streams to get the given slot:

```
int preferredSlot = 0;
int numberOfSlots = 3;
int capacityPerSlot = 3;
HashMap<Integer, Integer> slots = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

// put the values in...

int count = 0;

OptionalInt givenSlot = IntStream.rangeClosed(preferredSlot, numberOfSlots).filter(slotNumber ->
    slots.values().stream().filter(existingSlot -> existingSlot == slotNumber).count() <= numberOfSlots
).findFirst();

// This appears to be what you want to ultimately do...
givenSlot.ifPresent(slot -> {
  slots.put(count, slot);
  System.out.println("Given Slot: "+ slot);
});
```

Comment: With your improvement the code still does not work as it should, but I will try some slight changed and I think it will, the nested loop was my missing puzzle piece. When it comes to stream.. I have never worked with streams before, where would I implement this into my existing code?

Comment: @v_uztel Maybe you meant `slots.put(count, preferredSlot + i);` rather than `slots.put(count, i);`?

Comment: @v_uztel You would delete all your code, and replace it with the streams code. But again, I might not have understood you correctly. You want to find minimum slot number that has got less than 4 items in it right? And put `count` in that slot.

Comment: Not the minimum, the slot with the next lowest index. That's how its written in my instructions, I know it's a bit misleading. So if the preferred slot is 0, I would give him slots in that order: 1 -> 2 -> 3. What my code does at the moment with the nested loop is, when 1 is full, he counts up to 4 and then increments i to 2. and then he always puts 2 as the givenSlot.

Comment: @v_uztel I realised where I was wrong. It should be working now. I also showed more context around the stream solution. You can now replace your entire code with it, and it will work. But given that this is homework, I doubt you can use streams.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just managed to solve it aswell. The position of the valueCount2 = 0 was wrong, it has to be at the beginning.